# How to select rows based on column values of a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv

I want to select only rows that have fc_id == 2, and then delete those having duplicates. This is my input file:

[image]

I have been stuck on the first step only. After that I also need an output file where I will get my final data with fc_id==2 and no duplicates.

I tried this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'test.csv')
df2 = df[df["fc_id"]==2]

def condi(df2):
    df3[x] = np.where(df(df2)==2, 1, 0)
    return x
var = condi(df2)
#print(var)

with open('test.csv', 'r') as in_file, open('out_test.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    seen = set()
    if var == 1:
         for line in in_file:
            if line in seen: continue

            seen.add(line)
            out_file.write(line)
```

I am getting an error and when I tried to print(var) it said "'DataFrame' object is not callable".

Comment: `out = pd.read_csv(r'test.csv').query('fc_id == 2').drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76904320/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'test.csv')
df2 = df[df['fc_id'] == 2]
df2.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

For selecting dataframe given a certain equality condition:
`df=df[df['column_name'] == some_value]`

In your case:

```
df = df[df["fc_id"]==2]
```

For removing [duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), you can then use

```py
result_df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```